# What is the maximum size in MB of a batch write to Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am interested to know if the maximum size for a Firestore batch write is 10MB which is the [Maximum API request size](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#writes_and_transactions), or it's per Document eg 1MB leading up to 500MB. Or does this not matter?

Comment: I guess it depends on if a batch is implemented as a transaction with multiple API calls for each document, or if it's using a single Write API call. https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Write

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson I am not sure what you mean. I iterate over an array of documents and I set the batch doc. After that I do a `batch.commit()` and that calls I suppose some more internal API, not exposed to me.

Comment: Right, it depends on what the SDK is doing behind the scenes.  You could start digging into the details of the SDK you're using (they're all open source) and see which gRPC APIs are being called.

Comment: It looks like, even with a transaction, it still bundles everything up into a single commit as well.  So, I would say that for both batches and transactions, your limit is 10MB for the entire API call to commit the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell (using the nodejs SDK), a call to commit a batch will [result in a single call](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/3686816d4a98cabaee4bac089c34a335aa4ddbf8/dev/src/write-batch.ts#L668) to a [CommitRequest](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#commitrequest) API call, passing all documents in that call.  If that's the case, then I imagine the 10MB limit for the entire API call will apply.

Comment: This is correct. For batches bigger than 10MB, a `FirebaseError: Request payload size exceeds the limit: ...` will result